# rotation difference transformation with children

Tags: c++, opengl, math, matrix, glm-math

I have been struggling for some time with issue about some transform operations.
To be more precise determination of required transform to apply on each object to achieve values of another one.
I'm using C++ with OpenGL.

Let's say I have few objects in the scene.

[image: Figures]
Please note that it is for preseting problem only, not showing 100% accurate result. Testing values and results are on the bottom.

Red numbers are marks for group of objects.

All of objects have some position, rotation and scale parameters.

Group1 consists of two cones and one box.

Group2 consists of two cones.

What I'm trying to do is:
-select one cone from Group1, 
-calculate required rotation and position difference to match one of the cones in group 2, 
-check if applying same rotation offset and position (relative) change will also make second cone to work same way with second one in Group2. 
-If both matches, mark this transform as correct and apply it for other objects in Group1 (only box left). 
-To achieve something like Group3.

Instead I'm achieving some wrong results like in Group4. 
Cones in my cases matches , but other objects seems to have some problems.
Probably I have mistaken something in math.

Is it some local/global axis problem?

Here is how I'm doing this:
Calculation of rotation difference

```
//based on this: diff * q1 = q2  --->  diff = q2 * inverse(q1) formula
const glm::vec3 startRot = Group1ConeRotation;//degrees
const glm::vec endRot = Group2ConeRotation;//degrees
const glm::quat B = glm::quat(DegToRad(startRot));
const glm::quat C = glm::quat(DegToRad(endRot));
glm::quat A = C * glm::inverse(B);
A = glm::normalize(A); 
const glm::vec3 globalEulerRotOffset = RadToDeg(glm::eulerAngles(A));
//result
const glm::vec3 RotationDifference = globalEulerRotOffset;
```

Applying transform differences for all other objects from the first group (second cone, box)

```
glm::vec3 direction = Group1Cone.Position - Group1Object.Position; //check position difference between cone from first group where transformation was initialized
Group1Object.Position += direction;
glm::quat NewElementRot = GlobalRotationOffsetQuat  * glm::quat(DegToRad(Group1Object.Rotation));
NewElementRot = glm::normalize(NewElementRot);
Group1Object.Rotation = RadToDeg(glm::eulerAngles(glm::normalize(glm::quat_cast(NewElementRot))));
Group1Object.Position -= glm::vec3(glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(RotationDifference.x),
 glm::vec3(1.0f,0.0f,0.0f)) * glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(RotationDifference.y),
 glm::vec3(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f)) * glm::angleAxis(glm::radians(RotationDifference.z),
 glm::vec3(0.0,0.0,1.0)) * direction);
```

Comparision if Group1Cone2 matches Group2Cone2:

```
//just subtracktion of vec3 parameters and length calculation
if(glm::fastLength(Group2Cone2.Rotation - Group1Cone2.Rotation) < 1.0f && glm::fastLength(Group2Cone2.Position- Group1Cone2.Position) < 0.3f)
```

for this one I'm aware that it may produce false negatives if euler angles are much different, is there any easy way to determine if both objects are rotated the same by quaternion comparision? (with proper handling of scenarios where there is same orientation but with different quaternion)

And lastly how final matrix for each object is computed for rendering (just to show the order):

```
modelMatrix.SetIdentity();
modelMatrix.Translate(Object.position);
modelMatrix.ApplyMatrix(glm::mat4_cast(Object.Quaternion);
modelMatrix.Scale(Object.Scale);
```

And here is some testing results.

Before:

```
Group1:
Group1Cone1Rotation = (-90, 0, 0)
Group1Cone2Rotation = (-90, 0, 0)
Group1BoxRotation = (90, 0, 90)

Group2 (target):
Group2Cone1Rotation = (0, 0, -90)
Group2Cone2Rotation = (0, 0, -90)


Calculated GlobalRotationDifference to make Group1Cone1 matches Group2Cone1 rotation 
globalEulerRotOffset = (90, 0, -90)

Results after applying transform (Group4 instead of Group3):
Group1Cone1Rotation = (0, 0, -90) //matches
Group1Cone2Rotation = (0, 0, -90) //matches
Group1BoxRotation = (118.4572, -90.0001, -28.4566) //WRONG should be something like (0, 0, 90)
```

Comment: I guess you experience this misalignment of be box because the rotation difference includes a part that makes the box "stand on its feet". You won't see that because the cone is invariant to rotation about its own axis. Can you check the orientation of the cone? And you can get the similarity of two rotations with the absolute value of the dot product of the two rotations' quaternions. If it is one, they are equal.

Comment: When dealing with 3D transformation, the order of operation and the referential is critical. It is easy to make mistakes if you try and do the math by hand as you do here. It is generally simpler and less bug prone to just use 4d matrices for computations.